# Redefine function in AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Let's say you do this in AS2:

```
_root.foo = function(x){
//Do stuff
}
```

Is it possible to later redefine it like this

```
_root.foo = function(x){
//Do different stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can replace functions like this in AS2, unless you try to replace one that's implemented by the Flash runtime outside of ActionScript. So your example code will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It will work however if you redefine the function and go back to where you first defined the function, it will still stay the same unless you re-define it again.